# Free Function Block Diagram Editor

Tags: gratis, diagram

I have to produce XML files describing [functional block diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_block_diagram) connexions whith strict conformance to an existing, proprietary schema (XSD). I prefer using a graphical editor rather than hand write XML files.

[image: What's a FBD]

Here are the requirements:

- The tool should be free, preferably OpenSource
- The tool should be ergonomic, modern, using mouse and offer context menus
- The tool should save data as well formatted text (XML is welcome)
- No administrator rights required (top level req)
- The targeted operating system is Windows 2010 server but I have Linux boxes too and Java is not a problem
- Primary inputs, at the left of the diagram, should be picked up into a dictionary

Do you now some free product like that?

**EDIT**

I'm writing my own tool in Java. Once achieved, I'll post an answer with a link to download it from SourceForge. Stay tuned ;-)

Comment: Welcome to the site! We're going to need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. What operating system should the software run on? Do you have any preferences on how to produce the diagrams? What things are must-haves, and what things should it *not* do?